# ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR facing issue Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list

Tags: sql, reactjs, mern

```
app.post('/createproject', (req, res)=>
{
 console.log("i am post create project...")
 const sql = "INSERT INTO `projectlisting` (`proname` ,`prostartdate`, `proenddate` , `proreson` , `protype` , `prodivision` ,       `procategory`, `proproirity` , `prodept`, `prolocation` ,`prostatus`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

  const values = [
    req.body.proname || null,
    req.body.prostartdate || null,
    req.body.proenddate || null,
    isNaN(req.body.proreson) ? null : parseInt(req.body.proreson, 10),
    isNaN(req.body.protype) ? null : parseInt(req.body.protype, 10),
    isNaN(req.body.prodivision) ? null : parseInt(req.body.prodivision, 10),
    isNaN(req.body.procategory) ? null : parseInt(req.body.procategory, 10),
    isNaN(req.body.proproirity) ? null : parseInt(req.body.proproirity, 10),
    isNaN(req.body.prodept) ? null : parseInt(req.body.prodept, 10),
    isNaN(req.body.prolocation) ? null : parseInt(req.body.prolocation, 10),
    isNaN(req.body.prostatus) ? null : parseInt(req.body.prostatus, 10)
     
 ]
 console.log(values);

 db.query(sql, values, (err, data) =>{
     if(err){
         console.log(err)
         return  res.send('error');
     }else{
         return res.json(data);
     }
 })
});
```

error:

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
errno: 1054,
sqlState: '42S22',
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'",
sql: "INSERT INTO \`projectlisting\` (\`proname\` ,\`prostartdate\`, \`proenddate\` , \`proreson\` , \`protype\` , \`prodivision\` ,       \`procategory\`, \`proproirity\` , \`prodept\`, \`prolocation\` ,\`prostatus\`) VALUES ('Line',NULL,NULL,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN)"
}
```